# Browse local LAMP server by URL

Tags: networking, server, lamp

I'm working with a user who created a LAMP server to be used as an internal message board, of sorts. I need to be able to browse the site created via a browser URL. Ideally, we would have something like intranet.localdomain.com. I do not want this server to be public facing.

The server is running on Ubuntu 16.04. This is not an area I am familiar with so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Note that I can browse to the page using the IP of the server.

Comment: What kind of environment are you in? If you for instance have active directory, you do have functioning DNS. If so, add the desired name to DNS. If you don't have DNS, and more than a few computers, set up DNS.

Comment: Sorry yes, AD is in the environment and the DC's function as the DNS server.

Comment: Add a DNS record for your server then,. If it's the only site on that website server, that's all you need.

Answer (score -1):

This is easiest if you have access to all of the computers in your network. Here are the steps to take:

1. Set a static IP address for the server on the network.
2. On every computer, edit the hosts file (/etc/hosts on Linux) and name the local IP address. For example (replace the parentheses and their contents):

> (Local IP address) (tab) (desired hostname)

3. Restart all of the machines.

And you're done! You should now be able to access your server by typing the hostname into the address bar on any machine with an edited hosts file.

Comment: I have access to the computers, but there are ~250 in the environment. Getting the users away from them tends to be difficult as many take them home.

Comment: Do you have access to the router? I'm just thinking... with 250 nodes, you probably have one  that supports HOSTS or maybe static routes? If so, add the static IP of the server and the hostname to the router. If it is supported, then every system requesting the URL on the network will be sent to the correct server. Also, setting it up on the router makes it easy to manage access control and change configuration when/if the time comes. Is that an option?

Comment: With 250 computers, you don't handle DNS in the router. You handle it at an DNS server.

Comment: Snarky opinions aside - I am well aware of how DNS works. You can certainly set up a static route for a single  IP - in the router.  As for AS, I do NOT know what if any entries need to be made. A static route would be a quick and easily testable method for accomplishing the task as long as the server has a STATIC IP. I know because, I use this setup for a local testing server.

Comment: I fail to see how a static route would accomplish much. Routes are used for routing packages, not DNS lookups.